# Azure Search Indexer cannot retrieve a GeographyPoint filed from a document in DocumentDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

I'm having an issue while trying to index a document stored in a DocumentDb collection.

The datasource of the indexer was defined with a custom SQL to retrieve the changed documents. The document I want to index has a property called `LocationGP` which is a Microsoft.Spatial.GeographyPoint, and is mapped to a field of the index with the same name and defined as `DataType.GeographyPoint`

The error I get when trying to create the indexer is:

**Column 'LocationGP' is of type JObject that is not compatible with the field of type Edm.GeographyPoint in the index**

Any ideas?

This is the definition of the DataSource:

```
  return new DataSource()
                {
                    Name = "opportunities-datasource",
                    Container = new DataContainer()
                    {
                        Name = "Companies",
                        Query = @"SELECT    o.id,
                                            o.CompanyName,
                                            o.LocationGP,
                                            o.Location.CityName AS LocationCity,
                                            o.Location.StateName AS LocationState,
                                            o.Location.CountryName AS LocationCountry,
                                            o._ts
                                FROM Companies o WHERE o.DocType = 1 AND o._ts > @HighWaterMark"
                    },
                    Type = "documentdb",
                    Credentials = new DataSourceCredentials()
                    {
                        ConnectionString = String.Format("AccountEndpoint={0};AccountKey={1};Database=CompaniesDb", DocumentDbEndpointUri, DocumentDbPrimaryKey)
                    },
                    DataChangeDetectionPolicy = new HighWaterMarkChangeDetectionPolicy("_ts"),
                    DataDeletionDetectionPolicy = new SoftDeleteColumnDeletionDetectionPolicy("Status", "2")
                };
```

This is the document:

```
[{
    "id": "088e1e97-6d59-40ad-a9be-620fdc7938c7",
    "CompanyName": "Neptune",
    "LocationGP": {
      "Latitude": 39.8010482788086,
      "Longitude": -89.6436004638672,
      "IsEmpty": false,
      "Z": null,
      "M": null,
      "CoordinateSystem": {
        "EpsgId": 4326,
        "Id": "4326",
        "Name": "WGS84"
      }
    },
    "Location": {
      "CityName": "Springfield",
      "CountryName": "US",
      "StateName": "IL"
    },
    "Status": 1,
    "DocType": 1,
    "Timestamp": "2016-08-19T16:08:46.0481948Z",
    "_ts": 1471622922
  }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two more documents on Azure Search that explains what type of geography instances are accepted:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798938.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn946880.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Basically it needs to be in GeoJSON "Point" type format.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that `Edm.GeographyPoint` has a different format than `Microsoft.Spatial.GeographyPoint`.

To make it work I just created a class called `EdmGeograpyPoint` like this:

```
public class EdmGeographyPoint
{
    public EdmGeographyPoint(double longitude, double latitude)
    {
        coordinates = new double[] { longitude, latitude };
        type = "Point";
    }

    public string type { get; private set; }
    public double[] coordinates { get; private set; }
}
```

Then I replaced the type of the LocationGP property to EdmLocation.

Maybe there is a better solution, but documentation is confusing around this topic:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-howto-dotnet-sdk/

Comment: The document you refer to discusses the Azure Search .NET SDK. The examples that use Microsoft.Spatial.GeographyPoint are examples of using the Index API to push documents into the index. The SDK has special serialization logic to convert from GeographyPoint to Geo-JSON (a.k.a. Edm.GeographyPoint).

Comment: Please detail the solution more. I'm creating an Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models.Index, with fields declared like: new Field(nameof(SearchDoc.LastKnownPosition), DataType.GeographyPoint) { IsFilterable = true }. I have added "using Microsoft.OData.Edm;" but I can't find that "Edm.GeographyPoint" class that people talk about. The indexing is done like this :  await _searchIndexClient.Documents.IndexAsync(IndexBatch.MergeOrUpload(searchObjects)); where searchObjects are the objects having the EdmGeographyPoint field.

Yet, exception "a resource without a type name was found..."

Comment: More generally, everyone mentions "Edm.GeographyPoint" but I can't find that class anywhere? Or is it an enum?

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late with this answer, but I hope someone will benefit from it.

In my opinion, the cleanest way to deal with this is to continue using the 'built-in' classes/framework without having to create your own complex type.

The way I solved this was to use a JsonConverter that harnessed the Microsoft.Azure.Search.Serialization namespace. This namespace has the GeographyPoint extensions i.e. 'ReadGeoJsonPoint()' and 'WriteJson()' extensions.

I did the following:

```
 //    1. Create a JsonConverter
   using Microsoft.Azure.Search.Serialization;
   public class GeographyPointJsonConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(GeographyPoint);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            return reader.ReadGeoJsonPoint();
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            writer.WriteGeoJsonPoint(value as GeographyPoint);
        }
    }

    //2. Added the convert to the property I was looking to index
    [JsonConverter(typeof(GeographyPointJsonConverter))]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to use any of the above solutions successfully to pull GeographyLocation data out of our azure search instance. I was able to get it working with a minor adjustment to the custom geography location class. I just used the JSONtoC# converter to generate the class. This works with values containing coordinates and null Locations.

```
   public class ASLocation
    {
        [SimpleField(IsFilterable = true)]
        public string type { get; set; }

        [SimpleField(IsFilterable = true, IsSortable = true)]
        public List<double> coordinates { get; set; }
    }
```